# MSSQL 2005 server SUM by grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a SQL query which gives me the result of invoice lines.

I got all true information, but I want to group it. The problem is that I already grouped it.

There is my code:

```
WITH Agg1 AS(
SELECT  [Ship-to Name] As 'Pirkejas',
        [Order No_]
FROM [Artilux].[dbo].[Trivilita UAB$Sales Invoice Header]
)

SELECT  sil.[Document No_] as 'Pardavimo nr.',
    sil.[Shipment Date] as 'Siuntos data',
    sil.[Order No_] as 'Musu užsak. nr.',
    sil.[Customer Order No_]  AS 'Klientio užsak. nr.',
    a.[Pirkejas],
    CAST(sil.[Unit Volume]*sil.[Quantity] AS DECIMAL(16,4)) AS 'Tūris',
    CAST(sil.[Unit Price]*sil.[Quantity] AS DECIMAL(16,2)) AS 'Suma €'

FROM [Artilux].[dbo].[Trivilita UAB$Sales Invoice Line] sil

LEFT JOIN Agg1 a
ON a.[Order No_] = sil.[Order No_]

WHERE sil.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'PRK0820' 
AND sil.[Shipment Date] > '2015-09-01 00:00:00.000'
AND sil.[Shipment Date] <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)  AND sil.[Document No_] = 'TRV0093219'
GROUP BY    
        [Unit Price],[Quantity],
        sil.[Document No_],
        sil.[Unit Volume],
        sil.[Shipment Date],
        sil.[Order No_],
        sil.[Customer Order No_],
        a.[Pirkejas]
ORDER BY     sil.[Shipment Date] DESC
```

The result I get:

```
TRV0093219  2015-12-22 00:00:00.000 SO0184846   IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 0.2400  17.35
TRV0093219  2015-12-22 00:00:00.000 SO0184846   IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 0.8140  121.00
TRV0093219  2015-12-21 00:00:00.000 SO0184846   IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 0.0000  0.00
TRV0093219  2015-12-21 00:00:00.000 SO0184846   IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 0.0000  0.00
TRV0093219  2015-12-21 00:00:00.000 SO0184846   IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 0.0000  0.00
```

The result I need to get:

```
TRV0093219  2015-12-21 00:00:00.000 SO0184846   IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 1.054 138.35
```

Comment: Describe what you need in words rather than dumping data... That will increase the odds of getting a proper answer.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to remove [Unit Price] and [Quantity] from the GROUP BY.  Within the SELECT clause these should be aggregated, by wrapping a SUM() around those fields.

Comment: @destination-data i need to plus theese two last columns. if i do like you said, i got not theese numbers.. i got `0.7200 52.05
2.4420 363.00` while i need to get only 2 numbers. :) sorry for my english

Comment: Can you provide sample data for [Trivilita UAB$Sales Invoice Line]?  Preferably in format we can use to reproduce your example?

Comment: @destination-data in this table is about 50 columns.. in simple words, I am trying to count one invoice price, and volume. I get correct numbers, but I cant get grouping.. My example is simple, maybe my words is hard to understand. AS you see i got 5 lines which are same except two last collumns. So i need one line, and sum of last two collumns.

Answer (score 1):

Remove those columns from GROUP BY and add an aggregate function:

```
WITH Agg1 AS(
SELECT  [Ship-to Name] As 'Pirkejas',
        [Order No_]
FROM [Artilux].[dbo].[Trivilita UAB$Sales Invoice Header]
)

SELECT  sil.[Document No_] as 'Pardavimo nr.',
    sil.[Shipment Date] as 'Siuntos data',
    sil.[Order No_] as 'Musu užsak. nr.',
    sil.[Customer Order No_]  AS 'Klientio užsak. nr.',
    a.[Pirkejas],
    SUM(CAST(sil.[Unit Volume]*sil.[Quantity] AS DECIMAL(16,4))) AS 'Tūris',
    SUM(CAST(sil.[Unit Price]*sil.[Quantity] AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS 'Suma €'

FROM [Artilux].[dbo].[Trivilita UAB$Sales Invoice Line] sil

LEFT JOIN Agg1 a
ON a.[Order No_] = sil.[Order No_]

WHERE sil.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'PRK0820' 
AND sil.[Shipment Date] > '2015-09-01 00:00:00.000'
AND sil.[Shipment Date] <= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)  AND sil.[Document No_] = 'TRV0093219'
GROUP BY    
        sil.[Document No_],
        sil.[Shipment Date],
        sil.[Order No_],
        sil.[Customer Order No_],
        a.[Pirkejas]
ORDER BY     sil.[Shipment Date] DESC
```

Comment: now i got answer `TRV0093219 2015-12-22 00:00:00.000 SO0184846 IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 0.7200 52.05
TRV0093219 2015-12-22 00:00:00.000 SO0184846 IO1710379-C Living AS, Lade 2.4420 363.00`

Comment: @Rokas: Did you remove `[Unit Price],[Quantity] and [Unit Volume]` from `GROUP BY`? This will result in a single row, but the data is still wrong, as you seem return the same row 3 times. IMHO this should never happen, ``[Trivilita UAB$Sales Invoice Header]. [Order No_]` should be unique. If you can't fix this you must put your 1st query in a Derived Table and then add another GROUP BY on top of it.

Comment: yes i removed but now i still got two lines. First line is my true numbers but 3x bigger (answer * 3) and second line numbers both 0

Comment: The result you posted shows exactly the same data for the grouping columns, so this should be a single row.

Comment: Yes but it is not all data from both tables [Sales Invoice Line] and [Sales Invoice Header]. Maybe i need to select * and see which column is different, and than maybe will be any way to ignore that column?

Comment: You might remove it from GROUP BY and put a MIN or MAX aggregate on it instead.